# I want to calculate the running total without populating blank or future dates

Tags: powerbi, dax

I created a dax function that calculates a running total. The data is looking at the months actuals vs targets. The targets are already populated but there are no actuals for future targets of which we need to display both. I need to modify the dax function to put blank months as blank.

The code:

```
Cum_Actual =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Calv_ME_Telkom_Mobile_performance[Actual] ),
    FILTER (
        ALLEXCEPT (
            Calv_ME_Telkom_Mobile_performance,
            Calv_ME_Telkom_Mobile_performance[Region],
            Calv_ME_Telkom_Mobile_performance[Order_type]
        ),
        Calv_ME_Telkom_Mobile_performance[Month]
            <= MAX ( Calv_ME_Telkom_Mobile_performance[Month] )
    )
)
```

Expected results:

```
Date      |Actual|Target  |Running Total
01/04/2019|    85|     100|           85
01/05/2019|    52|      70|          137
01/06/2019|    69|      80|          206
01/07/2019|      |      70|
```

Comment: Is Cum_Actual a measure or a calculated column?

Comment: It's a measure.

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

```
Cum_Actual =
CALCULATE (
    IF(SUM ( Calv_ME_Telkom_Mobile_performance[Actual] ) < 1, "", 
SUM ( Calv_ME_Telkom_Mobile_performance[Actual] )),
    FILTER (
        ALLEXCEPT (
            Calv_ME_Telkom_Mobile_performance,
            Calv_ME_Telkom_Mobile_performance[Region],
            Calv_ME_Telkom_Mobile_performance[Order_type]
        ),
        Calv_ME_Telkom_Mobile_performance[Month]
            <= MAX ( Calv_ME_Telkom_Mobile_performance[Month] )
    )
)
```